# ¿Cómo desactivo la recarga automática de una página?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo un input type "text", estoy teniendo un problema al ejecutar la tecla "enter", ya que me recarga automáticamente la página, no requiero recargarla.

HTML

```
     <input type="text" id="TXTCit" style="text-transform:uppercase" width:100% class="form-control" maxlength="15" />
```

JS

```
     $("#TXTCit").keydown(function (event) {

        if (event.keyCode == 13)
        {
            /*  setTimeout(function () {
              //  var ale = alertify.alert("bien hecho");
                // ale.fadeOut(1500);
                alertify.alert("bien hecho");
            }, 10000);*/

           // alertify.alert("bien hecho");
            /*setTimeout(function () {
                // location.reload(false);
                alertify.alert("bien hecho");
            }, 80000);*/
            alertify.alert("bien hecho");
            //generar();
        }
        });
```

Al presionar "enter" me muestra el mensaje de alerta, pero se cierra automáticamente después de 2 segundos, no me da tiempo para leer mi mensaje, lo que requiero es que no se recargue la página hasta presionar "ok" en mi alerta.

Si alguien puede apoyarme se lo agradecería mucho.

Saludos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prueba con `event.preventDefault()` después de la declaración

```
  $("#TXTCit").keydown(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    if (event.keyCode == 13)
    {
        /*  setTimeout(function () {
          //  var ale = alertify.alert("bien hecho");
            // ale.fadeOut(1500);
            alertify.alert("bien hecho");
        }, 10000);*/

       // alertify.alert("bien hecho");
        /*setTimeout(function () {
            // location.reload(false);
            alertify.alert("bien hecho");
        }, 80000);*/
        alertify.alert("bien hecho");
        //generar();
    }
    });
```

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias, saludos. (: